# Cross-Origin Request Blocked with Ajax (box.com)

Tags: javascript

I try to send request by Ajax to get THE_DOCUMENT_ID, can you help me fix this bug

RESPONSE MESSAGE
"NetworkError: 401 UNAUTHORIZED - https://view-api.box.com/1/documents”

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://view-api.box.com/1/documents. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, you need to enable [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

Answer (score 0):

as per the new policies, Cross origin requests are blocked for AJAX Requests. (unless you have access to the remote server too add an extra HTTP header) if the server doesn't permit, you can't load resources from another origin. The best workaround would be loading the file with a server side scripting language (like PHP) in your same origin, then requesting that file from AJAX.

For more information see here  : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)